Rational sections of a sheaf
If $F$ is a sheaf on a top space $X$, my book defines the rational sections of $F$ as
$$ \text{Rat}(F) = \lim_{V\neq 0} F(U) $$
with no further explanation. I want to understand this definition, I cannot find wikipedia pages for it. I understand that to take a direct limit, the directed system needs to have upper bounds. But the if $V$ and $U$ are open, we cannot guarantee there is a nonempty open $W\subset V\cap U$.
Can someone explain this definition?

In the Zariski topology on an irreducible variety (or scheme), every nonempty open subset is dense. In particular, the intersection of any two nonempty open subsets is nonempty. Does your book have the hypothesis "irreducible" somewhere before this definition?
